# Finding ffmpeg installed version

Tags: bash, sed, ffmpeg

I have a cross machine script which needs to detect the version of ffmpeg as a regular version string (e.g. 2.3.8-1 or 4.1.3-0). The command

```
ffmpeg -version
```

returns a host of most likely very relevant information to others, but this is much more than what I need.

```
ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.10) 20160609
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.16.04.1 --build-suffix=-ffmpeg --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --cc=cc --cxx=g++ --enable-gpl --enable-shared --disable-stripping --disable-decoder=libopenjpeg --disable-decoder=libschroedinger --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-x11grab --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libzmq --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-libopencv
libavutil      54. 31.100 / 54. 31.100
libavcodec     56. 60.100 / 56. 60.100
libavformat    56. 40.101 / 56. 40.101
libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
libavfilter     5. 40.101 /  5. 40.101
libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
libswresample   1.  2.101 /  1.  2.101
libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
```

Answer (score 2):

At this point I have devised commands like this:

```
ffmpeg -version | grep 'ffmpeg version' | sed -e 's/ffmpeg version //' -e 's/[^-0-9.].*//'
```

or this one which only uses a single match:

```
ffmpeg -version | grep 'ffmpeg version' | sed 's/ffmpeg version \([-0-9.]*\).*/\1/'
```

that does the trick. This works with ffmpeg version 2.x, 3.x and 4.x as far as I have tested.

Any better solutions out there?

Comment: Interestingly, my ffmpeg (from the current arch package) reports as `ffmpeg version n4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers`; Probably a bug in the version display^^

Comment: Or an intentional packaging indication. You can probably just replace the space after 'version' in the sed command with something like [^0-9]* to ensure that the number is the first extracted character

Answer (score 2):

With sed, to capture and output non space characters after `ffmpeg version` string:

```
ffmpeg -version | sed -n "s/ffmpeg version \([^ ]*\).*/\1/p;"
```

**Edit:**

To capture only the version number without dist info:

```
ffmpeg -version | sed -n "s/ffmpeg version \([-0-9.]*\).*/\1/p;"
```

Please note that you don't need:

- to escape dot in `[.]`
- to pipe your `ffmpeg`to `grep` because `ffmpeg -version` string is in your sed pattern

Comment: This also catches the full version string, which can be distribution dependent like "2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1". Nice with the -n and p for duplication trick. I have this as my present solution: ffmpeg -version | sed -n 's/ffmpeg version \([-0-9\.]*\).*/\1/p;'